# 405 when submitting form to Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a webpage in html in which a user have to input a url into a textfield.

```
<form name="submitURL" method ="post">
<input type="text" name="url_target">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

When the user press the submit button a python script should intercept the data inserted by the user and pass it to another function inside this script.

Python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def indhtml() :
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/index.html', methods = ['POST'])
def result():
    result = request.form('url_target')
    link = result.link
    print (link)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app.run(debug = True)
```

the first render is fine and i can see the index.html page, but when i insert something in the textfield appears the error HTTP 405.

Do you have any suggestion for that? :(
Thanks!

Comment: This is Flask, not Django.

Comment: Thanks for the annotation Daniel, I'm learning both these days and I made confusion while writing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `action="{{ url_for('result') }}"` in your `<form>` tag, so you are submitting the form to the same page, which is not accepting POST requests.

Additionally, `request.form` is dict-like, so you need `[]` and not `()` to access it. `link = result.link` is going to fail too because there is no way that `link` attribute exists on the string you get from `request.form`...

Answer (score 1):

Your function `result()` returns nothing.

Comment: The point is not that i suppose.. I mean, the function will return the url in future, but the error remains even if i add something to return